# BeautifulSoup очистка вложенных тегов

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Всем привет!

Нужно взять из кода веб страницы только текст, который лежит в определенных тегах. Если в этих тегах, есть вложенные теги, их содержимое не нужно учитывать.

Например, мы имеем html код

```html
<div><p>Нужный мне текст  <a href="#">Не нужная мне ссылка</a> <span>данный текст также мне не нужен</span> </p> ТЕКСТ</div>
```

Как мне взять, все что есть в теге DIV и P, удалив при этом вложенные теги?

---

Из оптимального, что получилось:

```py
markup = '<div><p>Нужный мне текст  <a href="#">Не нужная мне ссылка</a> <span>данный текст также мне не нужен</span> </p> ТЕКСТ <a href="#">Не нужная мне ссылка 2</a><span>Спамный текст</span></div>'
root = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'html.parser')
div = root.select_one('div')
anchor_len = len ([ tag for tag in div.findAll() if tag.name == 'a'])
span_len = len ([ tag for tag in div.findAll() if tag.name == 'span'])
decomp_anchor = [ div.select_one('a').decompose() for i in range (anchor_len)]
decomp_span = [ div.select_one('span').decompose() for i in range (span_len)]
print(div.text)
```

Но насколько это оптимальный код? Просто `decompose()` удаляет первый тег в дереве, а нужно удалять все теги в дереве.

Comment: `decompose` удалит текущий тег, а не первый, не используйте выражения с `decomp_anchor` и `decomp_span`, это создается ненужный список, тут достаточно перебрать в цикле. Кст, в `div.findAll()` можно передавать название тега, а у полученного тега сразу вызвать `decompose`. Да и в питоне рекомендуется змеиная нотация, поэтому используйте метод-двойник `find_all`. Кст2, а аналогом `find_all` будет метод `select`. Методы `select` и `select_one` работают через css-селекторы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод `decompose` для удаление тегов.

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div><p>Нужный мне текст  <a href="#">Не нужная мне ссылка</a> <span>данный текст также мне не нужен</span> </p> ТЕКСТ</div>
"""

root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = root.select_one('div')
div.select_one('a').decompose()
div.select_one('span').decompose()

print(root)
# <div><p>Нужный мне текст    </p> ТЕКСТ</div>
```

Если элементов несколько, то используйте метод `select` для получения списка элементов, после проходите в цикле по-элементно и у каждого элемента вызывайте `decompose`:

```
...
div = root.select_one('div')

for x in div.select('a'):
    x.decompose()

for x in div.select('span'):
    x.decompose()

print(root)
```

Comment: спасибо, за пример.
Есть нюанс, если у нас много тегов <a href> внутри текста, decompose() удаляем только 1 тег. Нужно циклом проходится в данном случае?

Comment: @sanitarn, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо, значит правильно подумал.

Comment: @sanitarn, пожалуйста :)